# Type casting (multiple parameters of the same type)

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, casting

I have the following method declaration:

```
def method(alpha, size=10, logged_in=False, interactions=False):
    
    if not isinstance(logged_in, bool):
        logged_in = str(logged_in).lower() in ['true']
    
    if not isinstance(interactions, bool):
        interactions = str(interactions).lower() in ['true']
```

The `if` statements are needed because, for example, `interactions` would be falsely set to `True` if I pass `interaction="False"` as a parameter (so, I pass a String). While the above does the trick, I wonder if there is a more elegant way to achieve it (note that I have a lot of boolean parameters, beside `logged_in` and `interactions`, and I also have some `int` and `float` parameters. How could decorators be used here? Could one decorator be used for all `bool` parameters, and how could I make a general one (i.e., supporting `bool`, `float`, `int`, `string`)? I found the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841217/python-decorator-casting-checker) question potentially useful, but still wanted to check if there are better ways.

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this? IMO there's really no point in trying to sanitize arguments like this. You should just expect the callers to call your function correctly, because how many different possibilities are you going to sanitize? Would you also add support for `'yes'`/`'no'`? how about `'t'`/`'f'` or `'y'`/`'n'` or `'0'`/`'1'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this.

```py
def bool_fixer(func):
    table = {"true": True, "false": False}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(val, str) and val.lower() in table:
                kwargs[key] = table[val.lower()]
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@bool_fixer
def method(...):
    do something
```

after the decorator does its magic then all of the string "true" and "false" will turn into their python `bool` equivalent and you can skip all the checking in the `method` function.

If you want it to cover `ints` and `floats` too:

```py
import re
def converter(func):
    patterns = {r"\d*": int, r"\d*?\.\d*": float}
    table = {"true": True, "false": False}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(val, str):
                if val.lower() in table:
                    kwargs[key] = table[val.lower()]
                    continue
                for pattern in patterns:
                    if re.match(pattern, val):
                        kwargs[key] = patterns[pattern](val)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

or

```py
def converter(func):
    table = {"true": True, "false": False}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(val, str):
                if val.lower() in table:
                    kwargs[key] = table[val.lower()]
                elif val.isdigit():
                    kwargs[key] = int(val)
                elif re.match(r"\d*?\.\d*", val):
                    kwargs[key] = float(val)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

This decorator should reliably handle bools, ints and floats. As written this will modify keyword arguments that are str type. It first checks to see if the str is the words "[Tt]rue" or "[Ff]alse". The next test is checking to see if the str is an integer (a simple cast test works). Int is checked first because the formatting is more particular than float, since int must be only numbers, but float can contain decimal points. Finally, it tries a cast to float. If all of these casts fail, then we assume it is an actual str that shouldn't be tampered with.

```py
def cast_arguments(method):
    """decorator"""

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():

            # change special strings to bools
            if isinstance(value, str):
                if value.lower() == "true":
                    kwargs[key] = True
                elif value.lower() == "false":
                    kwargs[key] = False
                else:
                    try:
                        # change ints to int (int cannot have ".")
                        kwargs[key] = int(value)
                    except ValueError:
                        try:
                            # change floats to float (can have ".")
                            kwargs[key] = float(value)
                        except ValueError:
                            # this is an actual string
                            pass

        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class Test:
    @cast_arguments
    def method(self, logged_in=False, interactions=False, other=False):
        print("logged_in: ", logged_in, type(logged_in))
        print("interactions: ", interactions, type(interactions))
        print("other: ", other, type(other))


c = Test()
c.method(logged_in="1", interactions="True", other="3.14")
```

---

output:

```
$ python test.py
logged_in:  1 <class 'int'>
interactions:  True <class 'bool'>
other:  3.14 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: @kevin_was_here this approach works well too :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).